# unable to integrate MPU6050 with ros

Tags: imu, ros-kinetic, rosserial-arduino, rosserial-python, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get yaw pitch roll from an MPU6050 imu using the following code(some parts of code removed for clarity). Its getting uploaded

```
  #include <I2Cdev.h>
  #include <Wire.h>
  #include <MPU6050.h>



  #include <ros.h>
  #include <geometry_msgs/Vector3.h>

  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  geometry_msgs::Vector3 yaw_pitch_roll;
  ros::Publisher pubyaw_pitch_roll("yaw_pitch_roll", &yaw_pitch_roll);



  MPU6050 mpu;

  // Timers
  unsigned long timer = 0;
  float timeStep = 0.01;

  // Pitch, Roll and Yaw values
  float pitch = 0;
  float roll = 0;
  float yaw = 0;

  void setup() 
  {
    nh.initNode();
    nh.advertise(pubyaw_pitch_roll);

     //main problem here
      mpu.calibrateGyro();
  }

  void loop()
  {
    timer = millis();
    yaw_pitch_roll.x = yaw;
    yaw_pitch_roll.y = pitch;
    yaw_pitch_roll.z = roll;
    pubyaw_pitch_roll.publish( &yaw_pitch_roll );
    nh.spinOnce();

    delay(100);
  }
```

But when i try to run the following command in terminal after uploading:

`rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=57600`

I get the following error:

`[ERROR] [1517073128.320418]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino`

Now, I have run many arduino programs using same configurations( baud_rate)  and commands. But this is the only program thats giving me a tough time.

Also when i remove the following line:  `mpu.calibrateGyro();` the program runs fine.

Can anyone suggest me any workaround for this?

NOTE: I have tried to change the baudrate to `115200` and serial port is also right(other programs run fine) and message is not too big( i have sent the same message in other programs)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281046/unable-to-integrate-mpu6050-with-ros/) by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2018-01-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-30**:
Answer is working for you ?

**Comment by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on 2018-01-30**:
No. In the second link it is mentioned to run many commands. Everything works fine till
`./configure` After this I suppose an error crawls in here:
`checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c checking whether build environment is sane... yes /tmp/bcm2835-1.50/missing: Unknown` --is

**Comment by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on 2018-01-30**:
after this when i try to run `make` its giving me many warnings and when i try to run `make check` its showing
`Testsuite summary for bcm2835 1.50 ============================================================================ # TOTAL: 1 # PASS:  0 # SKIP:  0 # XFAIL: 0 # FAIL:  1 # XPASS: 0`

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-30**:
bro i not work on that till now so i don't know much Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the the solution for your problem
https://github.com/superjax/tinyIMU_arduino
https://github.com/chrisspen/ros_mpu6050_node
Only need to do some modification according  to needs

---

Originally posted by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) with karma: 216 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0